# Fancybox Issue with close button on button helper console

Tags: fancybox

I have a portfolio page with multiple images, which on a PC or Mac when hovered over with a mouse, bring up a mask with two icons, each of which launch two different Fancybox galleries for that thumbnail. There is also a quicksand plugin that lets you re-order the thumbnails and a callback to make sure Fancybox still works after the animation. I am using the button helper option in fancybox, which also brings up the button console at the top of the screen above the image. So far so good. The problem is on an ipad or iphone.

When you select an image by tapping on it, it behaves just as it would with a mouse. Two icons come up, tap on either et voila...Fancybox opens! However if you elect to close Fancybox using the close button on the button console on the top of the screen, instead of say clicking outside the open image, when you then select another quicksand filter category, the last category you chose (highlighted in red) disappears. Also the icons that appear when you tap on another image are transposed and no longer animate correctly. This problem does NOT occur if you close Fancybox by tapping outside the image, and you can run quicksand or tap on any number of images and the page works fine. Obviously, there is an issue with the button helper close button not closing Fancybox down. You can see this by also tapping on the last image you tapped on and whichever of the two icons that pop up normally and that you chose, is still highlighted in red. I am stumped as to a solution. I have included the link to the page below, so hopefully you can see the problem for yourself on an ipad or similar

www.1199sps.co.uk/inprogress.html

Hope someone can help!!

Comment: I am wondering if the problem is occurring because I am calling two separate fancybox scripts depending on which of the two link icons you tap on, to bring up two separate galleries. I have already raised a question about that here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401398/fancybox-button-console-moving-sideways-on-clicking-next-previous-and-duplicatin

Comment: Think I have solved it by adding this into the fancybox script:             afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
}); Now when you close using the button on the button helper console, it resets properly! TFFT!

Comment: Mobile issue solved, but I still have issue with buttons moving on mouseover on a PC, as per other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401398/fancybox-button-console-moving-sideways-on-clicking-next-previous-and-duplicatin